# Elastic search : how to query to return certain number products for different users

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of products which belong to few users, (the system is with ElasicSearch(ES), MySQL, Scala and ES Play Framework APIs [link](https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch)):

```
[
  { id: 1, user_id: 'jason', product: [...] },
  { id: 2, user_id: 'mike', product: [...] },
  { id: 3, user_id: 'mike', product: [...] },
  { id: 4, user_id: 'dan', product: [...] },
  { id: 5, user_id: 'bill', product: [...] },
  { id: 6, user_id: 'mike', product: [...] },
  { id: 7, user_id: 'dan', product: [...] },
  { id: 8, user_id: 'bill', product: [...] },
  { id: 9, user_id: 'mike', product: [...] },
  { id: 10, user_id: 'dan', product: [...] },
  { id: 11, user_id: 'bill', product: [...] },
  ...
]
```

I'd like to retrieve some certain number (for example, top 2 with highest matching score) products of best matching document based upon the user's id:

```
[
  { id: 2, user_id: 'mike', product: [...], _score: 100},
  { id: 3, user_id: 'mike', product: [...], _score: 95},
  { id: 4, user_id: 'dan', product: [...], _score: 90},
  { id: 5, user_id: 'bill', product: [...], _score: 80},
  { id: 7, user_id: 'dan', product: [...], _score: 70},
  { id: 8, user_id: 'bill', product: [...], _score: 65},
  ...
]
```

I tried [term facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html) on user_id, but I cannot find equal number products for each user currently, for example,

```
[ 
  { id: 2, user_id: 'mike', product: [...], _score: 100},
  { id: 3, user_id: 'mike', product: [...], _score: 95},
  { id: 4, user_id: 'dan', product: [...], _score: 90},
  { id: 5, user_id: 'bill', product: [...], _score: 80},
  { id: 6, user_id: 'mike', product: [...], _score: 75},
  ...
]
```

Term facets pseudo code:

```
/** query type is com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.ScalaHelpers.IndexResults[Product]
  * filtered is matching requirement filter, i.e. including keyword "fashion" 
  * limit is the size of returned users with matching document, i.e. 10 
  * finalQuery return 5 unique users based on tmpQuery result with 10 users
  * each user has 2 products finally
  */
tmpQuery = query.withBuilder(filtered).withSize(limit)
finalQuery = tmpQuery.addFacet(FacetBuilders.termsFacet("userId").field("user_id").size(5))
```

How to ensure everyone has 2 products, rather than mike has 3, dan has 1 and bill has 1? 
I mean, addFacet doesn't work now because finalQuery is based on tmpQuery, and tmpQuery returns 10 results which are more from mike due to higher matching score, how to update tmpQuery to reach the limitation of 2?)

Term facet cannot ensure unique users, it only return most frequent users. Actually, in this case, have to match products first, then retrieve its user_id then, so it cannot get users first and then their products.

Appreciate.

Comment: This is not a Scala question. Also, please post the code you wrote using `term facets`

Comment: It is more about ES query in Scala, I added terms facet pseudo code.

Comment: Why is it `size(5)`? I have never worked with elastic search, but since no one else is helping you, I'll try.

Comment: Thanks first. size(5) is 5 most frequent user_id, I want 5 unique users and each one has 2 products finally.

Comment: How about doing it in 2 steps then. First find the 5 most frequent users. Then **for each** find 2 most frequent products. Or, you will need to write a custom query (if that's possible).

Comment: Appreciate for suggestion, I will try and then update the post after figuring out.

Comment: please give us more details about the query code you are using! Which clients API are you using and such?

Comment: added, ES Play framework APIs with ScalaHelper

Comment: It seems need brand new ES features, top_hits aggregation. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/6124#issuecomment-43028315